# How can I use bat file to achieve ftp function without txt file? or the password can be encrypted in txt file?

Tags: batch-file, encryption, ftp, password-encryption

For avoiding the password shown in the txt file, can I achieve ftp function without the txt file?

So that I can write the encrypted password as parameter, and decrypt it in the bat file.

Or have any solution would achieve ftp function without any clear password?

Because of the rules of security, that couldn't have any clear password in the file. (even this just a temp file.)

So delete the txt file after the process was end couldn't solve the problem.

I'm using Windows FTP client.
My current code is shown as below.

**download.bat**

```
ftp -s:ftp.txt
```

**ftp.txt**

```
open servername
account
password
mget filename
quit
```

8/5 updated:
I have edited the bat file, but it's seem to can't login to the server:( 
The edited bat file :

**download.bat**

```
(
echo open localhost
echo username
echo password
echo ls
) | ftp -n
```

the return messages is **530 Please log in with USER and PASS first.**

But it is worked when I using txt to ftp.

So the states of ftp server is normal and the account/password is also correct.

It worked!!

**download.bat**

```
(
echo open localhost
echo user username password
echo ls
) | ftp -n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can feed the password to `ftp.exe` in standard input:

```
(
echo open ftp.example.com
echo user username password
echo mget filename
echo quit
) | ftp -n
```