# Automatic FTP batch file to send encryption keys in one file

Tags: batch-file, ftp, batch-processing

I am unable to find a way to have a batch file login to a FTP server without a different file being needed. The script is being run remotely on customer computers through Atera so we can grab customer bitlocker encryption keys then send a file that was created from the same script containing the keys. I would love some help for this on how to automatically login with the FTP username and password.

```
:: @echo off
set CUR_YYYY=%date:~10,4%
set CUR_MM=%date:~4,2%
set CUR_DD=%date:~7,2%
set SUBFILENAME=%CUR_YYYY%%CUR_MM%%CUR_DD%-%CUR_HH%%CUR_NN%%CUR_SS%
::Might move the computer name into variable SUBFILENAME 
echo
cd..
cd..
manage-bde -protectors c: -get > c:\BLK\BLK_%computername%_%SUBFILENAME%.txt
```

My computer has PURE-FTPd for the client.
If I were to manually use the FTP to send a file the command prompt would look like this but will not work in the batch file due to it not reading the username and password

```
C:\>ftp website.com
Connected to website.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 2 of 500 allowed.
220-Local time is now 13:59. Server port: 00.
220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
220 You will be disconnected after 15 minutes of inactivity.
504 Unknown command
User (website.com:(none)): USERNAME
331 User person@website.com OK. Password required
Password:PASSWORD
230-Your bandwidth usage is restricted
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
ftp> cd Test
250 OK. Current directory is /Test
ftp> put C:\BLK\Ethan.txt
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 60060
226 File successfully transferred
```

The password is hidden while typing it

Answer (score 0):

The standard FTP command-line client with Windows requires a response file (option `-s:file`) to work properly in batch mode. Otherwise, it works in interactive mode, and you'll need a separate process to pilot it through its `stdin`/`stdout` if you want an automatic operation.

Otherwise, you can use `psftp`, shipped with PuTTY.

Comment: The "separate process" can easily be [implemented using command block in the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45514171/850848). + The psftp is SFTP client, not FTP client.

Comment: No. Command block is **exactly** like a response file. A separate process, however, can also check error codes and execute a state machine: it doesn't only write to `ftp` program, it also READS its output and will wait/retry as needed. For `psftp`, maybe, that's a LOOOONG time that I didn't used a plain FTP server without any decent security... I always use SFTP or FTP/TLS, so I never checked if psftp is able (or not...) to connect to a bare FTP server.

Comment: Command block is *not exactly* like a response file in a context of a question that asks for a *single file* solution.

Comment: You missed the point. First, it doesn't do _AT ALL_ what a separate pilot process can do, unlike what you said first. Second, you can generate the response file to the `%TEMP%` folder from the batch, use it, then delete it, so you still have an unique BAT file to deliver. Third, even if I never tested it because I avoid this kind of borderline situations, I suppose that a too big command block may cause issues by filling the `stdin` buffer and maybe provoke a deadlock between finishing the command block and starting the process - a response file won't.

Comment: It seems that you believe that command block runs first, storing output to some buffer and then the `ftp` runs reading from the buffer. It does not. They run in parallel, and the output of the command block is streamed to the `ftp`. Otherwise [things like this](https://superuser.com/q/1366788/213663#1366837) wouldn't work.

Comment: I explain again... Put a REAL LOT of text echoed to a process that don't read from stdin fast enough. And pipe it to a process that can't read it at the same speed, whatever the reason is (ex: network/storage latency). Or use a program that purge `stdin` before accepting commands - already encountered some. That's what I call a borderline situation. It may, or may not, work. And that's only the 3rd point: command blocks are still not like a pilot process, and they aren't the only solution to get a single file distribution. Dude, I even already seen EXE programs embedded in BAT files...